# Tell if $A$ is diagonalized using it's characteristic and minimal polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization

$$A= \left( {\matrix{
   2 & 1  \cr 
   1 & 2  \cr 
 } } \right)$$

I already calculated that $f_A(x) = (x-3)(x-1)$. Also, the minimal polynomial must be also $(x-3)(x-1)$.

How can I use this information to determine if $A$ is diagonlized?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $v_1$ and $v_2$ two eigenvectors associated to the eigenvalues $3$ and $1$ respectively. $B=(v_1,v_2)$ is a basis for $\Bbb R^2$ and the matrix $A$ is similar to the diagonal matrix $\operatorname{diag}(3,1)$ relative to the basis $B$. A generalization of this  is

> **Theorem** *If a matirx $A\in M_n(\Bbb R)$ has $n$ distinct eigenvalues then $A$ is diagonalizable.*

Comment: Thank you. What about the case of $(x-3)^2$?

Comment: If the characteristic polynomial of the matrix $A$ is $(x-3)^2$ then $A$ is diagonalizable if and only if $A=3I_2$.

Answer (score 3):

A matrix or linear map is diagonalizable over some field if and only if its minimal polynomial is a product of distinct linear factors on the same field.

Answer (score 2):

your matrix $A$ is symmetric. for symmetric matrices, spectral decomposition theorem says that they are diagonalizable whether the eigenvalues are repeated or not.